# summary_table in R markdown not showing proper format

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to obtain a descriptive table with R markdown with the function summary table. I am quite new to both of them. The thing is that when i create the table I don't get a proper table but instead I get the one shown in the image (the numbers are OK).

How can I get the proper table format as I have seen in other posts where they use summary_table?

Thank you in advance.

**My code:**

````
---
title: "trial"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(haven)
library(qwraps2)
options(qwraps2_markup = "markdown")
df_bbdd <- read_sas("trial.sas7bdat")
our_summary <-
  list("Gender" =
         list("Female"       = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(sexo == 0, digits = 2),
              "Male"       = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(sexo == 1, digits = 2))
  )

descriptive_table <- summary_table(df_bbdd, our_summary)
```


```{r }
descriptive_table
```
````

[image: table output]

Comment: Maybe adding results='asis' in the chunk options?

Comment: So like ```{r, results='asis'} at the beginning of the chunk

Comment: Where I can download your dataset: ```trial.sas7bdat```? Add, please.